# Error with unicode characters in section with classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis

The following code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\section{propriet\`a di separazione}  % OK!
\section{proprietà di separazione}  % ERROR!
\end{document}
```

gives the following error:

```
! Argument of \@firstofone has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

I often got problems with the classicthesis package... is there some alternative?

Comment: You can try `\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}` then it will not use soul. Or simply don't use classicthesis. Imho it makes life only difficult.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I like the style and layout of classicthesis. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Extract the code you need from the sty. It has only around 700 lines, and most parts are alternatives you don't use.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini `\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}` works: what do you need more?